# AWS RDP connection problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I recently started working as an intern for a company and I have been using AWS to create ec2 instances. It worked fine when creating Linux instances but when I try to connect to a windows instance through RDP there's a big chance I'll be getting the following error:

"This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator."

The security group allows any IP to connect to any port (for now).

The weird thing is that this appears to be random, sometimes I can connect after restarting the instance a couple of times but it's getting quite annoying and I'ld rather avoid any unnecessary costs.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.